# ggplot Donut chart is not as desired

Tags: r, ggplot2, donut-chart

I am trying to create a donut chart using ggplot2 with the following data (example).

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(svglite)
    library(scales)

    # dataframe
    Sex = c('Male', 'Female')
    Number = c(125, 375)
    df = data.frame(Sex, Number)
    df
```

The code I used to generate donut chart is

```
    ggplot(aes(x= Sex, y = Number, fill = Sex), data = df) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_polar("y") +
    theme_void() +
    theme (legend.position="top") + # legend position
    geom_text(aes(label = percent(Number/sum(Number))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75), size = 3) +
    ggtitle("Participants by Sex")
```

The above code generated the following chart. Some how not convinced with the chart.

[image]

For our purposes, the following chart would better communicate the message. How do I create a chart like this. Where am I doing wrong in my code? I have googled with out any success. 
Thanks in advance for help.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

They aren't in the same 'circle' because they have different `x` values. Imagine it as a normal plot first (i.e. without `coord_polar("y")`) and this will become clear. What you really want is them set at the same `x` value and then stacked. Here I set `x` to `2` because it then makes a nicely sized "donut".

```
donut <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 2, y = Number, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(Number/sum(Number))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75), size = 3) +
  xlim(0.5, 2.5) +
  ggtitle("Participants by Sex")

donut
```

[image]

```
donut +
  coord_polar("y") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

Comment: @ Jack Brookes, Thanks, It helped me.